# Creating Expectation suite using Rule based profilers in Great Expectation

Tags: pyspark, great-expectations

I  have just started with Great Expectations and I am using Rule based profiler to create an expectation suite   following this [doc](https://docs.greatexpectations.io/docs/guides/expectations/advanced/how_to_create_a_new_expectation_suite_using_rule_based_profilers).

The  document does not have any information on  how  and where to save the  expectation suite and how can I use this suite to validate  the data that I get to see in future. can you please help me with some inputs. Appreciate your inputs

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that all steps until the result of the RuleBased Profiler are clear and start from this point on ([doc](https://docs.greatexpectations.io/docs/guides/expectations/advanced/how_to_create_a_new_expectation_suite_using_rule_based_profilers/)):

```
result: RuleBasedProfilerResult = rule_based_profiler.run(batch_request=batch_request)
```

From the result you can extract the created expectation_configurations:

```
expectation_configurations: List[ExpectationConfiguration] = result.expectation_configurations
```

When you have your list of expectation_configurations, you can add them to a suite. Suites can be created/loaded like this:

```
from typing import List
from ruamel import yaml

from great_expectations import DataContext
from great_expectations.core import ExpectationConfiguration
from great_expectations.rule_based_profiler import RuleBasedProfilerResult
from great_expectations.core.batch import BatchRequest
from great_expectations.rule_based_profiler.rule_based_profiler import RuleBasedProfiler
from great_expectations.checkpoint import SimpleCheckpoint
from great_expectations.data_context.types.resource_identifiers import ExpectationSuiteIdentifier
from great_expectations.exceptions import DataContextError

context = DataContext()

expectation_suite_name = 'my_suite'

try:
    suite = context.get_expectation_suite(expectation_suite_name=expectation_suite_name)
    print(f'Loaded ExpectationSuite "{suite.expectation_suite_name}" containing {len(suite.expectations)} expectations.')
except DataContextError:
    suite = context.add_expectation_suite(expectation_suite_name=expectation_suite_name)
    print(f'Created ExpectationSuite "{suite.expectation_suite_name}".')
```

When you have a fitting suite, you can add the configuration_expectations like this:

```
for expectation_configuration in expectation_configurations:
    suite.add_expectation(expectation_configuration=expectation_configuration)
```

Update your context so the added expectations are available:

```
context.add_or_update_expectation_suite(expectation_suite=suite)
```

With this, the expectations are now available in your suite. If you want to use a validator to test your expectations it can now be done like with every other suite you created by utilizing a checkpoint:

```
# fill in for your specific datasource
batch_request = {
'datasource_name': 'my_datasoure',
'data_connector_name': 'default_inferred_data_connector_name', 'data_asset_name': 'my_data_asset_name', 'limit': 1000
}

# get the validator from the context
validator = context.get_validator(
    batch_request=BatchRequest(**batch_request),
    expectation_suite_name=expectation_suite_name
)

print(validator.get_expectation_suite(discard_failed_expectations=False))
validator.save_expectation_suite(discard_failed_expectations=False)

# configure a checkpoint
checkpoint_config = {
    "class_name": "SimpleCheckpoint",
    "validations": [
        {
            "batch_request": batch_request,
            "expectation_suite_name": expectation_suite_name
        }
    ]
}
checkpoint = SimpleCheckpoint(
    f"{validator.active_batch_definition.data_asset_name}_{expectation_suite_name}",
    context,
    **checkpoint_config
)
checkpoint_result = checkpoint.run()

context.build_data_docs()

validation_result_identifier = checkpoint_result.list_validation_result_identifiers()[0]
context.open_data_docs(resource_identifier=validation_result_identifier)
```